# JS smartphone/tablet model/vendor detection from user agent

Tags: javascript, tablet, detection, smartphone

As far as there are no common rules for writing user agent in desktops, the same problem is on mobile devices.

But, unlike desktops, mobile browsers often write vendor and model of device into userAgent string.

Are there any lists with different devices user agents, or perhaps, some algorithm of detecting them?

**UPDATE 1**

I mean device detection, not CSS media queries, that are commonly used for using different CSS rules for different screen resolutions.

Suggest, you have userAgen string like that:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; LT28h Build/6.1.E.3.7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36`

From that string I can know, that page is loaded from `sony xperia ion` only by using some verification tables. **Do you know some?**

Comment: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Sounds like you should be using CSS media queries instead of browser sniffing, although nobody can tell because your question **doesn't contain enough information**

Comment: Stefan, that is only way for determining browser, not device itself

Answer (score -1):

I use following code to detect android device:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
alert('Android');
}
```